# Call to a member function toArray() on array -Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

```
   // $result=[];
 foreach ($chapter['chapter_content'] as $row) {
    $result = CoursePublishChaptercontent::create([
                                            'courseId' => $postdata[$i]['courseId'],
                                            'course_chapter_id' => $postdata[$i]['course_chapter_id'],
                                            'file_id' => $postdata[$i]['file_id'],
                                            'course_chapter_content_id' => $postdata[$i]['course_chapter_content_id'],
                                        ]);
}
dd($result->toArray());
```

`dd($result)` shows the below data. I cannot call `$result->toArray();` outside the `foreach` - it shows the error `Undefined variable: result`. When declaring `$result` before foreach as `$result=[];`, it shows the error `Call to a member function toArray() on array`. How can i fix it?Can someone tell me how to achieve this? I also tried declaring `$result` as `''` & `null` before foreach. Both shows errors `Call to a member function toArray() on string` & `Call to a member function toArray() on null` respectively.

```
App\Models\CoursePublishChaptercontent {#441
  #table: "course_publish_chapter_contents"
  #fillable: array:9 [
    0 => "course_chapter_id"
    1 => "file_id"
    2 => "courseId"
    3 => "course_chapter_content_id"
  ]
  #connection: "pgsql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:12 [
    "courseId" => 1
    "course_chapter_id" => 18
    "content_type_id" => 1
    "file_id" => null
    "course_chapter_content_id" => 17
    "id" => 106
  ]
  #original: array:12 [
    "courseId" => 1
    "course_chapter_id" => 18
    "content_type_id" => 1
    "course_chapter_content_id" => 17
    "content_description" => null
    "id" => 106
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: array:1 [
    "deleted_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #forceDeleting: false
  #enableLoggingModelsEvents: true
  #oldAttributes: []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can use the `collect()` helper to convert the result array into a collection and than you can use the `toArray()` method.
This is one way to do it:

```php
 $result = [];
 foreach ($chapter['chapter_content'] as $row) {
    $result[] = CoursePublishChaptercontent::create([
                                            'courseId' => $postdata[$i]['courseId'],
                                            'course_chapter_id' => $postdata[$i]['course_chapter_id'],
                                            'file_id' => $postdata[$i]['file_id'],
                                            'course_chapter_content_id' => $postdata[$i]['course_chapter_content_id'],
                                        ]);
}
dd(collect($result)->toArray());
```

Comment: that works. But y wasn't it possible to call toArray() directly on `$result`? what actually,the `collect()` does here?

Comment: Read the docs about the collection object, I think that clarifies a lot. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections The `$result` contains the just created `CoursePublishChaptercontent` model object and has a `toArray()` method. An array does not have any methods. So you need to convert the array into a collection object first.